# Enabling Device Admin gives syntax errors

Tags: android

The code below is my attempt at requesting the user's permission in my Android application to enable Device Administration. I quite litteraly copied the code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html, but I get a few errors.

```
FailedPasswordHandler fph = new FailedPasswordHandler();
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.getExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, fph);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
```

1) "The method getExtra(String, FailedPasswordHandler) is undefined for the type Intent"

2) "REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN cannot be resolved to a variable"

The second one seems like it's a global constant I could just define somewhere, but I don't know what value to set it to. The first one I really don't understand, because that line is in every code example I've come across. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing my code to this:

```
FailedPasswordHandler fph = new FailedPasswordHandler();
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, FailedPasswordHandler.class);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "'Cause I tell you that's why");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Please put your fixed code in your answer, and not in your question.